# Процесс загрузки страницы в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms

Делаю `POST` запрос с помощью `HttpWebRequest`, в котором есть информация с файла. 
Выполняю `Server.TransferRequest(/Client.aspx)` чтобы редиректить на нужную страницу. Проблема в том , что `Page_Load` выполняется одновременно в 2-х потоках.  Никаких потоков сам не создавал (намеренно).
В чем моя проблема?

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:1446/ClientForm.aspx"));
            request.Method = "POST";
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path + "email.com");
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            } 
        }
        //Server.TransferRequest("/ClientForm.aspx");
        Response.Redirect("/ClientForm.aspx");
```

Comment: и где Ваш `Page_Load`?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вы делаете сначала вручную POST-запрос, а затем на эту страницу и перенаправляете пользователя, отсюда и 2 раза. У вас с кодом что-то не так по ходу - ручной запрос не должен быть нужен.

Comment: @Андрей а как еще можно передать информацию из файла если не `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: @Igor не важно , что в `Page_Load` , тк даже когда он пустой, все равно 2 потока и 2 раза проход идет

Comment: @MikhailZnak, смотрите, что вы делаете, вы из своего приложения отправляете какие-то данные в своё же приложение через интернет. Это тоже самое, что вместо пары слов ртом писать своей жене письма и относить их на почту. Что мешает вам просто во втором (ClientForm.aspx) представлении прочитать нужный файл?

Comment: @Андрей как я понимаю, нужно передать ,например в Cookie, название файла, а во втором представлении выполнить нужную манипуляцию?

Comment: @MikhailZnak, да, но не обязательно в Cookie, можно просто как параметр GET/POST-запроса. Ну или записать в Session

Comment: @MikhailZnak, рекомендация. https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level1/1_1.php - здесь пример создания небольшого проекта на ASP.NET WebForms, выполните все шаги вместе с автором - это займет у вас 3-4 часа, но пользы будет гораздо больше, чем вы сейчас многое пытаетесь изобрести самостоятельно.

Comment: @Андрей спасибо большое , буду разбираться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работало 2 потока , тк  одновременно было сделано 2 запроса к конечной странице, а именно:

`(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:1446/ClientForm.aspx"));`

`Response.Redirect("/ClientForm.aspx");`

Как и советовали в комментариях, убрал `HttpWebRequest` и передал путь к файлу через параметр запроса.

```
Server.TransferRequest("/ClientForm.aspx?name=email");
```

На конечной странице уже и достал нужную информацию с сервера.